# how to trim values from multidimentional array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multidimensional-array, protractor, slice

```
    console.log(csvcontents.data.length - 8);
        for (let i = 7; i < csvcontents.data.length - 1; i++) {
          // console.log(csvcontents.data[i][0]);
          // arrayListFromCsvFile.push(csvcontents.data[i]);
           arrayListFromCsvFile.push(csvcontents.data[i]);
        }
        console.log(arrayListFromCsvFile); 
      }
```

This code prints the output as mentioned below

```
[
  [
    '2021-05-18',
    '17:07:32',
    'Informational',
    'abc',
    'xyz',
    "Web user 'abc' logged in ",
    '0x00'
  ],
[
    '2021-05-18',
    '17:07:32',
    'Informational',
    'xyz',
    'abc',
    "Web user 'abc' logged in ",
    '0x10'
  ],
]
```

is there any way to del the call values with index starting from `2,3,6`.
ie, i want only the  `2021-05-18`,
`'17:07:32'`,`'abc'`,`'Web user 'abc' logged in` in both the arrays

Comment: look at array splice https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: we don't see any `2,3,6`. what's the input look like?

Comment: thanks  @MisterJojo. It worked

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
    console.log(csvcontents.data.length - 8);

    //iterate through each data and return an new array that has all the required elements in array.

    const arrayListFromCsvFile = csvcontents.data.map((data) => {
       return [data[0], data[1], data[3], data[5]]
    })
    console.log(arrayListFromCsvFile);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this should work and what it does differently from other answers ?

Comment: @XouDo Here we can loop through each element on the array and return new array which has specific elements which we require.
If we are going to use destructing there are some variable that are assigned and not used.

Answer (score 1):

look at [array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```js
const data = 
 [ [ '2021-05-18'
    , '17:07:32'
    , 'Informational'
    , 'abc'
    , 'xyz'
    , "Web user 'abc' logged in "
    , '0x00'
    ] 
  , [ '2021-05-18'
    , '17:07:32'
    , 'Informational'
    , 'xyz'
    , 'abc'
    , "Web user 'abc' logged in "
    , '0x10'
  ] ] 
      
      
data.forEach(row=>
  {
  row.splice(6,1) // start with the last one,
  row.splice(3,1) // otherwise calculate with the offset 
  row.splice(2,1)
  })
  
console.log( data )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0}
```

Comment: yeah thanks i used console.log(csvcontents.data.length - 8);
        for (let i = 7; i < csvcontents.data.length - 1; i++) {
          // console.log(csvcontents.data[i][0]);
          // arrayListFromCsvFile.push(csvcontents.data[i]);

          csvcontents.data[i].splice(2, 1);  // 0 1 2 3 4 5    //2 3 5
          csvcontents.data[i].splice(2, 1);
          csvcontents.data[i].splice(4, 1);
          arrayListFromCsvFile.push(csvcontents.data[i]);
        }
        console.log(arrayListFromCsvFile);


This worked,Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can destructure array get the respective index data into variable and include it into result array.

```
function run() {
  console.log(csvcontents.data.length - 8);
  for (let i = 7; i < csvcontents.data.length - 1; i++) {
    const [a, b, c, d, e, f, g] = csvcontents.data[i];
    arrayListFromCsvFile.push([a, b, d, f]);
  }
  console.log(arrayListFromCsvFile);
}
```

eg

```js
const arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const result = [];
const [a, b, c, d, e, f, g] = arr;
result.push([a, b, d, f]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function modifiedArray (array){
      return array.map( ele =>  {
         return ele.filter( (el, i) => {
           return ![2,3,6].includes(i) ;
         })
      })
    }
    const data = [
          [
            '2021-05-18',
            '17:07:32',
            'Informational',
            'abc',
            'xyz',
            "Web user 'abc' logged in ",
            '0x00'
          ],
          [
            '2021-05-18',
            '17:07:32',
            'Informational',
            'xyz',
            'abc',
            "Web user 'abc' logged in ",
            '0x10'
          ],
    ]
console.log(modifiedArray(data))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
console.log(csvcontents.data.length - 8);// actual data starts from 8th row.Hence considering the count of lenght from 8th row
    for (let i = 7; i < csvcontents.data.length - 1; i++) {
      // console.log(csvcontents.data[i][0]);
      // arrayListFromCsvFile.push(csvcontents.data[i]);

      csvcontents.data[i].splice(2, 1);  // 0 1 2 3 4 5    //2 3 5
      csvcontents.data[i].splice(2, 1);
      csvcontents.data[i].splice(4, 1);
      arrayListFromCsvFile.push(csvcontents.data[i]);
    }
    console.log(arrayListFromCsvFile);
```

**Worked after using splice().**